# adding an ImageView to linearlayout throws target exception

Tags: android, android-gallery

Hello all

I have an array of ImageViews which are images I take with the camera.
but not saved on the sd or anything.

then I display all images in a gallery.

now I'm trying to create a preview of an image in that gallery. So an onclick of an image in the gallery will switch view and add the image to the linearlayout
like so:

```
private void ShowImagePreview (ImageView p_image, View p_view)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.preview);
    LinearLayout prevHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainHolder);

    p_image.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    p_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    prevHolder.addView(p_image);
}
```

but on this command: prevHolder.addView(p_image); i get a target exception.

I debugged and I see that p_image is in fact not null or anything like that...

I also tried:

```
ImageView test = new ImageView(this);
    test.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    test.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    prevHolder.addView(test);
```

and this one worked.

what can be the problem?..

thank you

edit:

this is the exception i get :
05-22 17:58:25.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11815): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I understand that this is because the image is already used in the gallery.
so how do i solve that?.

thank you

Comment: prevHolder might be null if you are using an R.id that is not used in the R.layout.preview xml.  Also, you can get a lot more information if you get the full exception name from LogCat.  If it's a NullReferenceException, then it's what I described, but it could be something else entirely

Comment: i checked the prevHolder is not null... the exception is a targetexception. but i dont see her details...

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective to examine LogCat and look at the *complete* stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: ok thanks! i see the exception. 
05-22 17:58:25.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11815): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

i guess this is because the image is allready used in the gallery.

now how do i make a duplicate of it or something?.. so i can use it agian?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix it, by passing Drawable to your method instead of ImageView, then create local ImageView variable and use setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) method - after that you should be able to add ImageView to your LinearLayout - prevHolder.

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing one or both of your views.  You should just instantiate a new ImageView to add to the RelativeLayout.  If you want to recycle views that are no longer part of the layout, you have to explicitly remove them from their parent by calling parent.removeView(view)